# How can I change a vector of strings all containing a keyword?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame called df2 that looks like this:
[image]

And I want to replace all the Model names that contain the string "ZOE" or another key word with just "ZOE", given that it is of Make "RENAULT" or another make. So, for example, I want ZOE DYNMAIQUE INTENS AUTO -> AUTO, and if the Model does not contain a string with the characters "ZOE" I want it to keep its model name.

I am new to python, and I have tried the below code with no luck.

```
df2['Model'] = df2['Model'].apply(lambda x: 'ZOE' if df1['Make']df2['Make'] == 'RENAULT' & df2['Model'].str.contains('ZOE') else df2['Model'])
```

The error I am receiving is 'other' should be pandas.NA or a bool. Got str instead.
Would be very grateful for any help or points as to where I am going wrong.
Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! One question: you are using a combo of `df1` and `df2`, is that correct? It does seem kinda wrong to me

Comment: Hey :)  Yeah my bad, I entered it into stackoverflow wrong. I have now edited it in stackoverflow. They should all be df2

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like you're not using `x` anywhere in your lambda. Try replacing `df2` with `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you need both the columns 'Model' and 'Make' in you `lambda`, you need to apply the lambda to all of `df2` (or at least to `df2[['Model', 'Make']]`.
Moreover, you want to loop on the rows of the Dataframes, so you have to pass the argument `axis = 1` to `apply` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).
Then, as suggested in the comments, to access the content of the rows, you should use `x` and not `df2`.
So (after a few more modifications), I would try something like this:

```
df2['Model'] = df2.apply(lambda x: 'ZOE' if (x['Make'] == 'RENAULT') & ('ZOE' in x['Model']) else x['Model'], axis=1)
```